# Cross tabbing results within a SQL Syntax

Tags: sql, t-sql

The below is a simple SELECT statement which I have created in my report writing software CorVu NG it accepts Derby Syntax, U2 syntax and T-SQL the "REPORTING.DAY" field is a column containing the day of the week e.g. a number from 1 to 7

```
SELECT A."REGIONAL.MAN" AS "R", A.AREA AS "A", A.BRANCH AS "Br", A.NAME, A.GROSS AS
"Sales", A.TARGET AS "Target1",
A."REPORTING.WEEK" AS "Week", A."REPORTING.DAY" AS "Day", A."SALES.YEAR" AS "Year"
FROM Branch A
WHERE (A."REGIONAL.MAN" > 0)
```

reporting day should be aliased as:

```
1 = Sunday
2 = Monday
3 = Tuesday
4 = Wednesday
5 = Thursday
6 = Friday
7 = Saturday
```

I know I need to add in some aggregates but... I need to:

```
(SUM(GROSS) / SUM(TARGET)
```

And give a total of this result per day running horizontal but  have no idea where to start with it.

The results should look like:

[image: Example results table]

R | A | BR | NAME | SUNDAY | MONDAY | TUESDAY | WEDNESDAY | ect

Hope someone can help, I am familiar to T-SQL but im not sure of which function to do this.

Comment: If reporting.day is a date or datetime datatype, the datename function will get you the names of the day.

Comment: Looks like you want `GROUP BY` ...

Comment: Hi no its an Interger 1=Sunday, 2=Saturday ect which I will need to use a CASE or something similar to change. but that isn't the issue its how to cross tab.

Comment: Hi by doing a GROUP BY this will not cross tab my results in will still display them as a linear results column? I need the results to be in columns SUNDAY MONDAY TUESDAY WEDNESDAY THURSDAY, the image did not load sorry so you cant see the example

Comment: A google search on "sql server pivot query" will give you lot's of interesting things at which to look.

Comment: Hi Dan thanks I have had a Google on this but it didn't yield any results I could apply to this situation really.. I will keep Googling in the mean time for any more results.

Comment: Dan I don't suppose you have any links on 'SQL Server pivot tables' which you have come across which you think may help?

Comment: example of pivot http://blog.sqlauthority.com/tag/pivot/

Answer (score 1):

Looking over your original question I noticed that you mentioned U2.  You could create 7 additional dictionary items, and keep track of the days of the weeks.  The following is an example of a dict item that will count the Monday birthdays.

```
:CT DICT MEMBERS MONDAY
MEMBERS:

MONDAY:
I
OCONV(BIRTHDATE, "DW"); IF @1 = 1 THEN "1" ELSE "0"

MONDAY
10R
S
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what you're looking for, I believe:

```
SELECT 
    A.[REGIONAL.MAN] AS [R], 
    A.[AREA] AS [A], 
    A.[BRANCH] AS [Br], 
    A.[NAME], 
    SUM(CASE A.[REPORTING.DAY] = 1 THEN A.[GROSS]/A.[TARGET] ELSE 0 END) AS [Sunday]
    SUM(CASE A.[REPORTING.DAY] = 2 THEN A.[GROSS]/A.[TARGET] ELSE 0 END) AS [Monday]
    SUM(CASE A.[REPORTING.DAY] = 3 THEN A.[GROSS]/A.[TARGET] ELSE 0 END) AS [Tuesday]
    SUM(CASE A.[REPORTING.DAY] = 4 THEN A.[GROSS]/A.[TARGET] ELSE 0 END) AS [Wednesday]
    SUM(CASE A.[REPORTING.DAY] = 5 THEN A.[GROSS]/A.[TARGET] ELSE 0 END) AS [Thursday]
    SUM(CASE A.[REPORTING.DAY] = 6 THEN A.[GROSS]/A.[TARGET] ELSE 0 END) AS [Friday]
    SUM(CASE A.[REPORTING.DAY] = 7 THEN A.[GROSS]/A.[TARGET] ELSE 0 END) AS [Saturday]
FROM Branch A
WHERE A.[REGIONAL.MAN[ > 0)
```

Comment: Hi @Metaphor the below error is received: BIC00004. SQL Parser encountered "SUM" at line 7, column 5.
Was expecting one of the following:
 ,,INTO,FROM,...